# NestJs puts everything in main.js

Tags: typescript, compilation, nestjs

I have nest.js application and when I serve it, the `dist` folder contains only `main.js` containing all the code. I need separate `.js`, `.d.ts` files to be created and maintain project structure inside `dist` folder. How can I do it?

Here's my `tsconfig`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "rootDir": ".",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "declaration": true,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "importHelpers": true,
  "target": "es2015",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
  "skipLibCheck": true,
  "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
  "types": ["node"],
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your `nest build` is using `webpack` to transpile the code from `ts` to `js`. `webpack` bundles everything into a single file and is used by default in monorepo modes. If you really want to use `tsc` in monorepo mode, do note that the output will be somewhat difficult to handle because of the way `tsc` works when importing files from outside of `baseUrl`. To force `nest build` to use `tsc` you can set the [compiler option in the `nest-cli.json` file](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo#specified-compiler)